# Won't change image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Javascript code:

```
function changeImage(src, imgMap)
{
    document.getElementById('screenshots').src = src;

    if (imgMap != null)

    {

        var newmap = document.getElementById(imgMap);
        var origin = document.getElementById("map1");
        origin.innerHTML = newmap.innerHTML;
    }
    curser_normal();
}

function curser_normal()
{
    document.body.style.cursor = 'auto';
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="centeredImage">
    <img class="logo" id="screenshots" border="0" src=".\pics\test1.png" usemap="#map1">
</div>

<map id="map1">
  <area shape="rect" coords="103,224,169,242" onclick="changeImage('.\pics\test2.png', 'nextpage');" onmouseover="cursor_wait();" onMouseout="curser_normal();">
  <area shape="rect" coords="30,92,56,116" onclick="changeImage('.\pics\test3.png', 'anotherpage');" onmouseover="cursor_wait();" onMouseout="curser_normal();">
</map>
```

Comment: format your code as mentioned above & only provide the code we need to see, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: check network console in your browser, are you putting correct image path?

Comment: My apologies.  OK so the first image loads fine and the other two are in the same folder so path should be the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies within your function call. It is not possible to give an url as an argument like you do now. The function will use the following url: `.pics   est2.png` as input. What you can do is the following thing:

change this `\`:

```
changeImage('.\pics\test2.png', 'nextpage'); // results in: .pics   est2.png
```

to `/`:

```
changeImage('./pics/test2.png', 'nextpage'); // results in: ./pics/test2.png
```

In that case you will have it working

Comment: @joshrt24 nice! Could you mark my solution as the answer by clicking on the check button and upvote my answer?